# What is the purpose of writing "*" when declaring pointer variables in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm learning about pointers in C, and I understand that pointer variables are typed so that the programme knows how many bytes to read when dereferencing the variable, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int x = 1025;        // ints are assigned 4 bytes, hence 00000000 00000000 00000100 00000001
  int *p = &x;         // address of x in memory
  char *p0 = (char *)p; // will have the same value as p does, i.e. &x

  printf("%d\n", *p); // reads four bytes, returns 1025
  printf("%d\n", *p0);    // reads one byte, returns 1

  return 0;
}
```

My understanding is that the `int` part of `int *p` is to tell the programme how many bytes of memory to read when dereferencing. However, what does the `*` part do? When I try `int p = &x;`, I get a warning of some sort but the programme still seems to work. How is the instruction `int p = &x;` different to `int *p = &x;`, and what doesn't C like about it?

I tried the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  int x = 1025;
  int p = &x; // No "*"
  char p0 = (char *)p; // Ditto

  printf("%d\n", *p);
  printf("%d\n", *p0);

  return 0;
}
```

I am in VS Code, and the Bash terminal seems to output okay:

```
1025
1
[1] + Done
```

Whereas the C/C++ gcc window gives errors:

```
Starting build...
In function 'main':
7:11: warning: initialization of 'int' from 'int *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    7 |   int p = &x;
      |           ^
8:13: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    8 |   char p0 = (char *)p;
      |             ^
8:13: warning: initialization of 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
10:18: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
   10 |   printf("%d\n", *p);
      |                  ^~
11:18: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
   11 |   printf("%d\n", *p0);
      |                  ^~~

Build finished with error(s).
```

My question is, what is it unhappy about, and why is it unhappy, given that the programme seems to output okay? And what does the "*" in the variable declaration even do?

Comment: When defining a pointer, the `*` is just a part of the type name. `int x` is declaring a variable of type `int`. `int *x` is declaring a variable of type "pointer to `int`"

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'd be a bit wary of stating it like that, lest OP tries something like `int * x, y`.

Comment: I guess my question is, what is the necessity of having a separate type for pointers to things? If the address of `x` is say 1000, and you set `int p = &x;`, then won't the variable p just contain 1000, whether you called it `int p` or `int *p`?

Comment: They are inherently different things, with different semantics and different use. And you are also ignoring that `int` is not guaranteed to be large enough to hold an address either. Not to mention that your code would completely fall apart for any other data-type, such as user-defined `struct`s

Comment: Pointers do not necessarily have the same ranges or representations as the pointed types (in most cases they don't).

Comment: The comment "ints are assigned 4 bytes" is not correct.  On some platforms, ints are 4 bytes, but on others they are not.  To assume they are a particular size is to set yourself up for future confusion.

Comment: For `int p` compiler allocates number of bytes required for `int` type (e.g. 4 bytes). For `int *p` compiler allocates number of bytes required for pointer, and assumes when pointer dereferenced, it points to another number of bytes required for `int`. Number of bytes required for pointer may differ from number of bytes required for int (i.e. on x86_64). On some platforms pointers may be a composite type, e.g. contain segment:offset pair.

Comment: "the Bash terminal seems to output okay": no, it means that at a certain point you compiled the program without error and got an executable which gives that output, then you modified it and introduced some errors, so you get "Build finished with error(s)", but the binary was *not* overwritten. So the binary you are running does *not* correspond to the source code you are trying to compile. Some IDEs (Visual Studio, if I remember correctly) are more explicit about this.

Answer (score 4):

Although comments have touch on one reason, an `int` might have insufficient bits to represent an address, a fundamental reason is that C uses types to help avoid mistakes and provide richer expressions.

You could have a programming language in which each variable was just a cell in memory, say 32 bits. You could write `a + b` for an integer add of `a` and `b` and `a +' b` for a floating-point add. However, when somebody write `a + b` where they meant `a +' b`, the program would do an integer add, and the compiler would not know there was a mistake there.

When the variables have types, the compiler can do some error checking. If `a` or `b` is a pointer, and the programmer accidentally types `a * b`, the compiler produces an error message saying you cannot multiply a pointer. If pointers were just `int` objects, this error-catching message would not be possible.

Another feature is that some errors just vanish. When you write `a + b`, the compiler will automatically use an integer add or a floating-point add, according to the types of `a` and `b`.

Also, if pointers were just `int`, `a + b` would always add some number of bytes `b` to `a`. However, when the compiler knows that `a` is a pointer to an `int`, `a + b` calculates the address that is `b` `int` elements beyond `a`, not just `b` bytes beyond `a`. So `a + b` calculates using the type that `a` points to, and `a` can point to objects of different types, such as 1-byte `char` objects, 4-byte `int` objects, or 36-byte `struct` objects.

Answer (score 3):

> How is the instruction `int p = &x` different to `int *p = &x`, and what doesn't C like about it?

In the first statement, the type of `p` is `int`. The type of `&x` is `int *`.  There is a type mismatch when attempting to initialise an `int` with a pointer to `int`. Numbers and pointers have different semantics and different applicable operators. In general, you shouldn't mix them unless you want to do some arithmetic with the value of the pointer. The types `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` are suited for that.

In the second statement, the type of `p` is `int *` and `&x` is also `int *`. The types match and the compiler accepts it.

> What is the purpose of writing "*" when declaring pointer variables in C?

C has a distinctive syntax feature called "declarations mirror use". The declaration says that it is declaring an identifier called `p`, which, when subjected to the `*` unary operator, yields a type `int`. It is like an artificial dereferencing operation just to show the final type of the operation.

Comment: If you convert a pointer to `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`, do some arithmetic on that to change the value, and convert the changed value back to a pointer, the C standard doesn't guarantee anything about the resulting pointer. On a modern system using "flat" pointers, and a non-hairy C implementation, it will probably do what you expect. I think the proper way to do what I described would be to use `char *` to do the arithmetic.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, `int` and `int *` are different types, namely 'integer' and 'pointer-to-integer' respectively.

What you have to be careful about, as mentioned in comments, is that the asterisk `*` goes with the variable name, so that you can declare integers and pointers-to-integers in the same line.

For example, `int * p, x;` will declare a pointer-to-integer `p` and an integer `x`.

---

You mention that you understand how it is important to know what you have a pointer to, and therefore why we need different pointer types such as `char *` and `int *`.

If we consider a hypothetical language that is like C but where we use `int` for all pointers, how would the computer know what this is a pointer to? Clearly some additional context is needed.

So it makes sense that we notate pointers with some modification of the type we wish to point to. Note that this will also work for user-defined types such as `struct`, which makes the concept of pointers more broadly useful.

---

If we look at what data a pointer holds, it will in fact be a number that looks mostly like an integer. But importantly, the size of that pointer is based on the way memory addressing works on the system for which that code is written and compiled. This does not necessarily have to match the size of the `int` type.

An `int` is often 16, 32, 64 bits, but other sizes are possible.

Similarly, a pointer (e.g. `int *`) could be any of these sizes, but the two are not necessarily the same.

This explains why your program runs in VS Code; it looks like you may be lucky enough to be on a system where the sizes of `int` and `int *` are compatible, i.e. that `int` is large enough to hold all the bits which make up an `int *`, so the address is always interpreted in exactly the same way. This is not a good way to write code, since it will be very difficult to move between architectures. For example, this code might work on your PC, but not on a Raspberry Pi, or an Arduino.

Another possibility is that you just get lucky in the way memory is laid out, and what is lost in the conversion does not affect the output of your program. It is never a good idea to rely on this.

---

---

As to why GCC complains about this, we can go through the warnings (which won't block compilation) and the errors (which cause compilation to fail) line by line:

```
7:11: warning: initialization of 'int' from 'int *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
7 |   int p = &x;
  |           ^
```

This warning tells you that you are storing a pointer (in this case `int *`) in a variable of a type which is not expected to hold a pointer (in this case `int`). The operator `&` takes the address of the variable in `x`, and so the expression `&x` has the same type as `int *`, and the compiler expects that you will store this in a variable with type `int *`. When you try to store this in just a regular `int`, it warns you that this may not be what you intend, since, as discussed above, an `int` may not be able to contain all the data needed for an `int *`. If you are sure you want to do this, you can explicitly typecast to an integer (`int p = (int) &x`), but this is usually a bad idea.

---

```
8:13: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
8 |   char p0 = (char *)p;
  |             ^
```

This warning tells you that you are making a pointer (in this case, pointer-to-char, i.e. `char *`) from an integer which does *not* have the same size as the pointer. This leads to the issues discussed above where the address you get out in `p0` may not be the same as the result of `&x`.

---

```
8:13: warning: initialization of 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

This warning is the same as the first, but for `char` instead of `int`. Since `char` and `int` are both integral types, the explanation is largely the same, but `char` is almost certainly too small to contain an entire address.

---

Now we get into the errors. These are the reason that your program doesn't compile, as opposed to just things the compiler suggests that you double-check.

```
10:18: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
10 |   printf("%d\n", *p);
   |                  ^~
```

The reason this is an error, is that `*` has several different meanings in C. Up until now, we have only talked about this as a modifier, to convert a type into a pointer-to-type, but the same symbol used outside of a declaration, has the opposite effect: taking a pointer-to-type, and giving you back the value stored at that pointer. This is the dereference that you talk about right at the start of your question. This is an error because the compiler does not know how to interpret whatever bits it finds at the address stored in the `int`, since we don't know what type this is intended as a pointer to! Rather than guessing at your intentions, the compiler says you need to fix it.

It might look obvious to the reader, since this is in a call to `printf`, and you've given a format string that makes it clear this should be an `int`. But this isn't something that the compiler is capable of figuring out, and there are certainly situations where this would be completely ambiguous (e.g. overloaded methods).

---

```
11:18: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
11 |   printf("%d\n", *p0);
   |                  ^~~
```

This is exactly the same error as the previous.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that pointer variables are typed so that the programme knows how many bytes to read

This is a bit of an over-simplification. Pointers are used to that we may refer to the same object from multiple places of the program. Pointers have a referenced type, but they are also a type of their own.

So `int* p` declares a pointer to the referenced type `int`, but `p` has a type too and that type is `int*`.

Now as it happens, de-referencing a pointer to get the value of the object can also be done with a `*` symbol, but in this case it has nothing to do with the `*` in the declaration `int*`. In `printf("%d\n", *p);` the `*` is the unary *indirection operator*. Different things.

The compiler knows how many bytes to print because it knows how large the referenced type `int` is. But that doesn't mean that we can do wild and crazy casts as we please. You can't take a pointer like `double*` and set it to point at the memory location of an `int` - these are different and non-compatible types.

The reason why your code happens to work is because the character types specifically is a special case - they are the *only* type in C that can be used to create a pointer and inspect an object of a different type, byte by byte.

As a beginner, you should pretty much never use type casts anywhere. The rules of type and pointer conversions are many and intricate.

Answer (score 1):

```
1  int x = 1025;
2  int p = &x; // No "*"
3  char p0 = (char *)p;
4  printf("%d\n", *p);
```

In line 2 you try cram the memory address of `x` into an `int`, but depending on your platform a memory address might not fit into an `int`. Typically if you're on a 64 bit platform (very likely nowadays), a memory address takes 64 bits and also depending on the platform and `int` might only be 32 bits.

Ditto for line 3 except that a `char` is **always** 8 bits by definition.

In line 4 `*p` doesn't make sense, because `p` is an `int` and not a pointer to `int`.

That's pretty basic C knowledge and it is explained in the chapter dealing with pointers in your C text book.

Comment: Re “That's pretty basic C knowledge…”: That is irrelevant. OP is not asking what the C rules are. They are asking why.